# Equivalence relation - help needed with proving

Tags: equivalence-relations

let E be an Equivalence relation on A (non-empty group) is the next argument true or not, justify your answer:

$\exists x~(\forall y~(xEy)\lor \exists y~\forall z~(zEx\lor zEy)) \to \forall x~\exists y~\exists z((x\neq y)\land (x\neq z)\land (xEy\lor xEz))$

---

Let $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $E = \operatorname{Id}a$

Is that a good counter-example?

Comment: To be clear, what is $\operatorname{Id}a$ meant to be?

Comment: {<1,1>,<2,2>,<3,3>}

Answer (score 0):

The formula is not valid: Let $A$ have only one element.

Your example doesn't satisfy the condition of the implication (has more than two equivalence classes), hence it's not a counterexample.

Comment: ok, is the argument true? if so could you please show me how to prove it?

Comment: No, it's not true. A one element set provides a counterexample.